# how to restore used disk space from a new partition windows 10

Tags: partitioning, external-hard-drive, disk-space

Empty External Hard drive has 6GB of used disk space on a fresh partition after reformatting. WinDirStat and WizTree[WizTree Image link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JVCGi.png) both show it as unknown.

I have system restore turned off. What could this be? How can I remove it.

[image]

Comment: Can you provide us with a screenshot?

Comment: and, what does "Disk management" show?

Comment: Disk management also shows 6GB in use

Comment: As a separate partition?

Comment: Not able to attach 3rd link for disk management but its just one partition for the whole drive of which 6GB shows up as used space.

Comment: You uploaded the same picture twice.  You are running `WinDirStat` with an Administrator user correct?

Comment: Reattached Wiztree image link. Also running WinDirStat as Admin

Comment: Here is some additional information: I deleted the partition and created 2 partitions instead of one on the disk. Now instead of 6.3 GB unknown I have 3.75GB unknown on each partition.

Answer (score 0):

I do not have any idea of why this was happening but I am able to resolve it via a workaround. After I saw that unknown space was proportional to partition size, I deleted all the partitions and created a new one with only 5GB and rest unallocated. The unknown space was again proportional but this time very low. Then I extended this small partition by adding all the remaining unallocated space. Here are the new screenshots from WinDirStat and WizTree. Would be great to see if anyone has a clue of what could be going on. But atleast now I do not have 6GB worth of unknown. Thanks

[WinDirStat New](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E2fJo.png)

[WizTree New](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H3b9a.png)